# Overriding method in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jsx, tsx

```
export class Person extends Component<...>{
    getName(){
        console.log('Person')
    }

    render(){
        this.getName()
    }   
}

export class Programmer extends Person{
    getName(){
        console.log('Programmer')
    }

}
```

Calling `new Programmer().render()` what should be logged? I see Person in my code. Why is that?  Any resources would be helpful.

Comment: Not the exact code. It is a react native app. I'll add more details

Answer (score 0):

Works in the typescript playground: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gWAFDQOgAcBXAIxAEthoBzeAFwDkwBbeACgEoAuaANxSUAJjnyEJwdKhDwAdCBS0OAcgTJ0KrngkBfPDsKkK1aInhphSbn0EixEiQwAWlCHPrM2nbeIK7CPH1cPFBIGFhEJUQ2dkRoeAAPBgthCKRUNAcjcioaTxZ2GwEhUUNHaCk0GXlFZTUo2hjWOK1y6GCgg1w0eAB3OEbmuO4PRkKfAG4gA)

The console prints "Programmer". There might be a different issue with your code that for whatever reason makes it not work, but the snippet you provided is perfectly fine and working.

A helpful way to iron out the issue is to try and make a `minimal reproducible example` of your problem, because often you'll find the issue yourself trying to make one.

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem, flag to close instead of answering.

Comment: @Snow That would not help anybody, an answer can provide hints suggesting a different approach and proving that OP's code does indeed work. Maybe it could be a comment though, I'd agree with that.

Comment: A question whose problem cannot be reproduced does not help anyone either.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the issue. I will update the question once I can repro